# Selenium on Edge doesn't invoke onchange() when calling SelectElement.SelectByValue()

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, windows-10, microsoft-edge

I have the following HTML:

```
<select onchange="redirect(this)" style="position:relative;top:3px">        
    <option value="?locale=fr">Français</option>        
    <option value="?locale=en">English</option>     
    <option value="?locale=zh">Chinese</option>     
</select>
```

In my Selenium test case, I do:

```
[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//select[not(option[1][@value='-1'])]")]
protected IWebElement ComboBoxLanguageInternal { get; set; }
protected SelectElement ComboBoxLanguage => new SelectElement(ComboBoxLanguageInternal);

this.SelectLanguage("en");

public void SelectLanguage(string locale)
{
    ComboBoxLanguage.SelectByValue("?locale=" + locale);
}
```

This works for all browsers and platforms. The language select element is switched from "Français" to "English" and the JavaScript function `redirect()` is executed. The only exception is MS Edge on Win10 Desktop: Here, the value is also switched to "English" but the JavaScript onchange event is not invoked.

Any workarounds?

I have already tried (with no success):

```
if (Params.Target.IsEdge)
{
    ComboBoxLanguage.WrappedElement.Click();
    ComboBoxLanguage.WrappedElement.FindElement(By.XPath(".//option[text()='English']")).Click();
}
```

Comment: Might be quickest to raise an issue at: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues as it certainly smells like a bug.

Comment: I downloaded WebDriver for Windows Insiders (Version: 2.1) for Windows 10 Version 1511 (OS Build 14271.1000), and it still has the same bug. :-(